# The purpose of NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR

Tags: iccube

I need the clarification about the meaning and purpose of `NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR` when defining calculated member. 
As I understood so far the purpose of `NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR` is to tell icCube that if `NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR` measure is null then entire calculated measure is null, so icCube does not need to evaluate calculation any further? Is that right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR property is used in calculated members to speed up some internal calculations. It defined a measure, or measure group, that has the same empty behavior as the calculated member.

An example,

```
MEMBER [Calculated] as [Measures].[Amount] * 23
```

As we can see from the formula when [Amount] is empty [Calculated] member will be empty. you could have another case :

```
MEMBER [Calculated] as [Measures].[Amount] * [Fx Rates].[Euros]
```

Here it's going to be empty if any of the two members is empty, for simplicity you could again define your [NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/cellProperties/NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR.php) only on [Amount] as you know the is always an Fx rate.

So we coud define in icCube

```
MEMBER [Calculated] as [Measures].[Amount] * [Fx Rates].[Euros], NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR='Amount'
```

**What is the use ?**

It's mainly used in icCube to speed up axis NON EMPTY  tag and when callling [NonEmptyX](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/NonEmptyX.php) function.

Pay attention that if you define it wrongly, using a wrong measure, you might find yourself with less members than expected ( NON EMPTY on axis, NonEmptyX function ... )